# How create Postgres database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want write project using database library (**SQLAlchemy**). When I use **SQLite**, all works good, but when I deploy project on server **(Heroku with Postgres plugin)**, It doesn't work. This is code for my database:

```
class UserBase(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    nickname = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    server = Column(Integer)
    language = Column(String(2))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<UserBase(nickname='%s', server='%s', language='%s')>" % \
            (self.nickname, self.server, self.language)
```

I have *engine* & *Base variable*:

```
engine = create_engine(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
Base = declarative_base()
```

In *DATABASE_URL* link to base on **Heroku(Postgres)**. For create database I write in Interactive Python Console:

```
from user_base import Base, engine
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

After these manipulations in the server logs it gives this:

`sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange) integer out of range`

**How to fix problem? If you needs in info, asking.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set type of *server* as **String**, indicated that the *server* is a string and this is helped me.